# Can orbital angular momentum of an electron be changed?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electrons, magnetic-moment

In a lab at my university they are working on a project that deals with changing the "net magnetization" of a material by "flipping" the spins on some electrons.

Is orbital angular momentum not something they're concerned about because it is not something that they can effect?

Comment: The lab has responded that the angular momentum of the materials they're working with averages out to zero effect on magnetic momentum, but they did not specifically answer if the angular momentum of an electron can be changed.